# Export excel page design to Jasper .jrxml file

Tags: excel, jasper-reports

My clients doen't know nothing about JasperReports *.jrxml* files. Because of that they give me reports design in an Excel file. Then I create jrxml by hand.

It is possible to export Excel pages into a jrxml file?

Comment: Do you want to embed some *Excel* file into the *JR* template (*jrxml*)?

Comment: No, I want to generate a jrxml from an Excel file.

Comment: Maybe possible but you need to do this by your own: Write a excel-to-jrxml converter. Won't be easy :)